# Html get user local directory path

Tags: javascript, html, path, directory

On my web app i have a textbox where client have to enter a path eg. C:\test and in that folder a file will be generated. The question is instead of manualy writing C:\test is there a way he can get this directory path with window that explores his system - like when uploading file.

Comment: this is not possible, browser don't allow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common use case is, the user clicks on a link and a file will be downloaded into his machine. This is usually done with anchor tag and the HTML5 download attribute. Here is an example:

```
<a href="~/images/abc.jpg" download>Click here to download </a>
```

The download action will be depended on the user's browser settings. In google chrome there is an option

> "Ask where to save each file before downloading"
>   [image]

if it is checked, user will get a file explorer pop-up to select the download location.

Comment: @MasterYi There is no other way to achieve the desired result as JavaScript in the Browser is sandboxed.

Comment: as i haven't find a better solution i will mark this as answer